# Creating a distance map from OpenStreetMap data

Tags: openstreetmap, distance

I would like to create a distance map using OpenStreetMap objects as input objects. To explain what I mean with distance map, let's look at the wikipedia definition:

> A distance transform, also known as distance map or distance field, is a derived representation of a digital image. [...]
>   The map labels each pixel of the image with the distance to the nearest obstacle pixel.

Imagine, for example, one wants to create a distance map for Sweden, indicating the distance for each pixel to the nearest alcohol takeway (OSM key: shop, OSM value: alcohol). This would require the following steps:

1. Gather all OSM data for the area inside the country borders of Sweden
2. Define pixel spacing of desired raster map (e.g. 1m or 1 km etc.)
3. Calculate distance for every pixel of that map to nearest alcohol shop OSM map feature using a to-be-defined distance metric (e.g. Euclidian distance)

While I have a clear conceptual idea of how to do it, I don't know where to start implementation-wise.

Is there a good Python API that allows to do such a thing without too much overhead?

Or is it easier to achieve my goal in QGIS?

Comment: I am guessing you will have to use PostGIS and pgrouting. [This](https://anitagraser.com/2017/09/11/drive-time-isochrones-from-a-single-shapefile-using-qgis-postgis-and-pgrouting/) post might get you started.

Comment: GDAL has the `Proximity (raster distance)` algorithm that might be what you're asking for. You can use it in QGIS.